# Hibernate core being included from spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gradle

I have a gradle project that has the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile("com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-c3p0:5.2.12.Final")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.44")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-log4j2'
}
```

And has the following to apply the spring boot plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE")
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I include the spring boot plugin, an older version of hibernate-core seems to be being imported into my project (5.0.12.Final). But my code uses the 5.2.12.Final hibernate-core library.

I can't understand exactly why the hibernate core library comes with the spring boot plugin, as I can't see it listed in its dependencies on maven central, however when I remove that dependency, the older version of hibernate seems to disappear.

I've tried excluding the module when declaring the dependency but that doesn't seem to be syntactically correct when excluding in the buildscript section.

Has anyone else had this problem? Any workarounds to exclude that version? Or maybe my setup all together is wrong.. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the output of `gradle dependencies`? The output is pretty verbose and should explain which dependencies are pulled and why. You can always [exclude some unwanted dependencies](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-exclude-specific-transitive-dependencies-of-something-i-depend-on/17991) and pull your own alternative instead.

Comment: Run `gradle dependencies` - analyse the resulting output. Exclude unwanted. Although, TBH, you’re betting off sticking with the version of Hibernate Spring wants and excluding your manual version. Furthermore, Hibernate should be a `runtime` dependency.

Comment: You aren't using the `hibernate-core` dependency you have the `hibernate-c3p0` dependency which is something completely different.

Comment: @M.Deinum hibernate-c3p0 has hibernate-core as a transitive dependency. Hence i don't need to import it explicitly.

Comment: @Turing85 I did run that but can't seem to see any indication that hibernate-core is pulled in from anything other than hibernate-c3p0.. would that be because its a dependency in the buildscript enclosure?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I would do that, but Hibernate 5.2.12 has some handy Query features that I wouldn't mind using, but if I have to I guess I'll have to refactor my code to be 5.0.x compatible

Comment: The point is due to the fact that you aren't included it, The Spring dependency management plugin will manage the version instead of you. Hence you get a different version. On another note you shouldn't be using the pooling support in Hibernate, instead you should use a proper connection pool and configure that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured this one out after many hours/
Seems obvious now after a bit more research, the problem was due to spring boots own dependency management, so all I have to do is specify the version of a particular module I want to use (if spring boot already includes it), and it worked! Here is what I added to my build.xml file

```
dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependency 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.12.Final'
    }
}
```

Comment: For those using Maven and Spring Boot. It worked for me by specifying <hibernate.version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate.version> under the properties node.